# Restoring public.layer_styles table from PostGIS dump

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, xml

I created a PostGIS database on a PostgreSQL server and stored some QGIS styles (in **public.layer_styles**). When dumping and restoring the database only this table gives me an error and stays empty.

I tried only dumping the public schema as .backup and .sql. What's wrong with xml?

```
 pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "layer_styles": FEHLER:  invalid XML content
DETAIL:  line 1: StartTag: invalid element name
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
 ^
CONTEXT:  COPY layer_styles, Zeile 1, Spalte styleqml: â€ž<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis version="2.8.1-Wien" minimumScale="...â€œ
```

-- Dumped from database version 9.3.10 to version 9.4.5 <- is this the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this statement `SET XML OPTION DOCUMENT;` at the beginning of the SQL backup file.

Source : https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10079

Comment: This is what I was looking for! But only works with plain sql dump.

Comment: What are you using ?

Comment: I confirm that this answers work, however as mentioned this only work when you can specify this option. In my use case I migrated a database using a custom dump created by pg_dump and restored using pg_restore. I got a COPY error on public.layer_styles so I restored it separately using plain SQL format.

Comment: I am getting a duplicate key error when trying to restore layer_styles in SQL format. Can you post your pg_dump and restore command (if other than "\i dump.sql")? I'm using the following to dump styles table: pg_dump -U postgres dbase -n public -t layer_styles --format=p --data-only -f  dump.sql